# Application can not be run after being installed

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

After installing my application on mobile, the Open option in dialog box is disabled. The app was created with android studio 1.4 and it was installed on Android 4.4.4. The application icon does not appear in the menu.
Excuse me for my bad english!

Comment: What your problem exactly?

Comment: You installed your application by running your code in Android Studio? Are you sure it installed successfully?  Were there any errors?

Comment: Did you set your applications main activity intent filter as main and Launcher in the AndroidManifest.xml  ?  (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: thank you all, there were no installation errors, I was just misconfigured
<action android: name = "android.intent.action.MyActivityName" />
instead of:
<action android: name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
it works!
thank you @chughes